# Java Remove First Line from byte[]

Tags: java, arrays, bufferedreader, filereader

I have a base64 data of a text/csv file. When changing the byte array to string im getting the lines of my files as expected. But if headerExist key is true i just want to remove the first line of my file in the fileContent string.

I tried changing the byteArray data to BufferedReader lines, then remove the line from the reader but couldn't make it out.

Someone pls help me to remove the first line if header exist.

```
public static String getFileConetentReadableData(byte[] byteArrayData, boolean headerExist) {

            String fileContent = new String();

            byteArrayData != null && byteArrayData.length > 0
            fileContent = new String(byteArrayData);

            return fileContent;
        }
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can substring the fileContent.
`String cleanLine = fileContent.substring(fileContent.indexOf("\n"));`

Comment: I believe this should be `substring(fileContent.indexOf("\n")+1)` As it stands the '\n' at the end of the header line will be the first character of `cleanLine`.